# Office 365 SMTP Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria

Tags: magento2, system-config, smtp

I'm trying to configure SMTP settings on the Magento store as follows:

[image]

but when I test, I have this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You me get answer: here [Authentication unsuccessful](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/535-57139-authentication-unsuccessful/6a12c8e7-3078-41c8-a4c0-1d9a0eda2ec0)